# ValueError after attempting to use OneHotEncoder and then normalize values with make_column_transformer

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

So I was trying to convert my data's timestamps from Unix timestamps to a more readable date format. I created a simple Java program to do so and write to a .csv file, and that went smoothly. I tried using it for my model by one-hot encoding it into numbers and then turning everything into normalized data. However, after my attempt to one-hot encode (which I am not sure if it even worked), my normalization process using make_column_transformer failed.

```
# model 4
# next model
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)
btc_data = pd.read_csv(
    "/content/drive/MyDrive/Science Fair/output2.csv",
    names=["Time", "Open"])

X_btc = btc_data[["Time"]]
y_btc = btc_data["Open"]

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")
enc.fit(X_btc)

X_btc = enc.transform(X_btc)

print(X_btc)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_btc, y_btc, test_size=0.2, random_state=62)

ct = make_column_transformer(
    (MinMaxScaler(), ["Time"])
)

ct.fit(X_train)
X_train_normal = ct.transform(X_train)
X_test_normal = ct.transform(X_test)

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3)

btc_model_4 = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
  layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
  layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
  layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
  layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
  layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
  layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")
])

btc_model_4.compile(loss = tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                      optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam())

history = btc_model_4.fit(X_train_normal, y_train, batch_size=8192, epochs=100, callbacks=[callback])

btc_model_4.evaluate(X_test_normal, y_test, batch_size=8192)

y_pred = btc_model_4.predict(X_test_normal)

btc_model_4.save("btc_model_4")
btc_model_4.save("btc_model_4.h5")

# plot model
def plot_evaluations(train_data=X_train_normal,
                     train_labels=y_train,
                     test_data=X_test_normal,
                     test_labels=y_test,
                     predictions=y_pred):
  print(test_data.shape)
  print(predictions.shape)

  plt.figure(figsize=(100, 15))
  plt.scatter(train_data, train_labels, c='b', label="Training")
  plt.scatter(test_data, test_labels, c='g', label="Testing")
  plt.scatter(test_data, predictions, c='r', label="Results")
  plt.legend()

plot_evaluations()

# plot loss curve
pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot()
plt.ylabel("loss")
plt.xlabel("epochs")
```

My normal data format is like so:

```
2015-12-05 12:52:00,377.48
2015-12-05 12:53:00,377.5
2015-12-05 12:54:00,377.5
2015-12-05 12:56:00,377.5
2015-12-05 12:57:00,377.5
2015-12-05 12:58:00,377.5
2015-12-05 12:59:00,377.5
2015-12-05 13:00:00,377.5
2015-12-05 13:01:00,377.79
2015-12-05 13:02:00,377.5
2015-12-05 13:03:00,377.79
2015-12-05 13:05:00,377.74
2015-12-05 13:06:00,377.79
2015-12-05 13:07:00,377.64
2015-12-05 13:08:00,377.79
2015-12-05 13:10:00,377.77
2015-12-05 13:11:00,377.7
2015-12-05 13:12:00,377.77
2015-12-05 13:13:00,377.77
2015-12-05 13:14:00,377.79
2015-12-05 13:15:00,377.72
2015-12-05 13:16:00,377.5
2015-12-05 13:17:00,377.49
2015-12-05 13:18:00,377.5
2015-12-05 13:19:00,377.5
2015-12-05 13:20:00,377.8
2015-12-05 13:21:00,377.84
2015-12-05 13:22:00,378.29
2015-12-05 13:23:00,378.3
2015-12-05 13:24:00,378.3
2015-12-05 13:25:00,378.33
2015-12-05 13:26:00,378.33
2015-12-05 13:28:00,378.31
2015-12-05 13:29:00,378.68
```

The first is the date and the second value after the comma is the price of BTC at that time. Now after "one-hot encoding", I added a print statement to print the value of those X values, and that gave the following value:

```
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (3, 3)    1.0
  (4, 4)    1.0
  (5, 5)    1.0
  (6, 6)    1.0
  (7, 7)    1.0
  (8, 8)    1.0
  (9, 9)    1.0
  (10, 10)  1.0
  (11, 11)  1.0
  (12, 12)  1.0
  (13, 13)  1.0
  (14, 14)  1.0
  (15, 15)  1.0
  (16, 16)  1.0
  (17, 17)  1.0
  (18, 18)  1.0
  (19, 19)  1.0
  (20, 20)  1.0
  (21, 21)  1.0
  (22, 22)  1.0
  (23, 23)  1.0
  (24, 24)  1.0
  : :
  (2526096, 2526096)    1.0
  (2526097, 2526097)    1.0
  (2526098, 2526098)    1.0
  (2526099, 2526099)    1.0
  (2526100, 2526100)    1.0
  (2526101, 2526101)    1.0
  (2526102, 2526102)    1.0
  (2526103, 2526103)    1.0
  (2526104, 2526104)    1.0
  (2526105, 2526105)    1.0
  (2526106, 2526106)    1.0
  (2526107, 2526107)    1.0
  (2526108, 2526108)    1.0
  (2526109, 2526109)    1.0
  (2526110, 2526110)    1.0
  (2526111, 2526111)    1.0
  (2526112, 2526112)    1.0
  (2526113, 2526113)    1.0
  (2526114, 2526114)    1.0
  (2526115, 2526115)    1.0
  (2526116, 2526116)    1.0
  (2526117, 2526117)    1.0
  (2526118, 2526118)    1.0
  (2526119, 2526119)    1.0
  (2526120, 2526120)    1.0
```

Following fitting for normalization, I receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in _get_column_indices(X, key)
    408         try:
--> 409             all_columns = X.columns
    410         except AttributeError:

5 frames
AttributeError: columns not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in _get_column_indices(X, key)
    410         except AttributeError:
    411             raise ValueError(
--> 412                 "Specifying the columns using strings is only "
    413                 "supported for pandas DataFrames"
    414             )

ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

Am I one-hot encoding correctly? What is the appropriate way to do this? Should I directly implement the one-hot encoder in my normalization process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using **OneHotEncoder** is not the way to go here, it's better to extract the features from the column **time** as separate features like year, month, day, hour, minutes etc... and give these columns as input to your model.

```
btc_data['Year'] = btc_data['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.year
btc_data['Month'] = btc_data['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.month
btc_data['Day'] = btc_data['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.day
```

the issue here is coming from the **oneHotEncoder** which is getting returning a **scipy sparse matrix** and get rides of the column "Time" so to correct this you must re-transform the output to a **pandas dataframe** and add the "Time" column.

```
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")
enc.fit(X_btc)
X_btc = enc.transform(X_btc)
X_btc = pd.DataFrame(X_btc.todense())
X_btc["Time"] = btc_data["Time"]
```

one way to **countournate** the **memory issue** is :

1. Generate two indexes with the same random_state, one for the **pandas data frame** and one for the **scipy sparse matrix**

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_btc, y_btc, test_size=0.2, random_state=62)
X_train_pd, X_test_pd, y_train_pd, y_test_pd = train_test_split(btc_data, y_btc, test_size=0.2, random_state=62)
```

2. Use the pandas data frame for the **MinMaxScaler()**.

```py
   ct = make_column_transformer((MinMaxScaler(), ["Time"]))
   ct.fit(X_train_pd)
   result_train = ct.transform(X_train_pd)
   result_test = ct.transform(X_test_pd)
```

3. Use generators for load data in train and test phase ( this will get ride of the memory issue ) and include the scaled time in the generators.

```py
def nn_batch_generator(X_data, y_data, scaled, batch_size):
   samples_per_epoch = X_data.shape[0]
   number_of_batches = samples_per_epoch / batch_size
   counter = 0
   index = np.arange(np.shape(y_data)[0])
   while True:
       index_batch = index[batch_size * counter:batch_size * (counter + 1)]
       scaled_array = scaled[index_batch]
       X_batch = X_data[index_batch, :].todense()
       y_batch = y_data.iloc[index_batch]
       counter += 1
       yield np.array(np.hstack((np.array(X_batch), scaled_array))), np.array(y_batch)
       if (counter > number_of_batches):
           counter = 0


def nn_batch_generator_test(X_data, scaled, batch_size):
   samples_per_epoch = X_data.shape[0]
   number_of_batches = samples_per_epoch / batch_size
   counter = 0
   index = np.arange(np.shape(X_data)[0])
   while True:
       index_batch = index[batch_size * counter:batch_size * (counter + 1)]
       scaled_array = scaled[index_batch]
       X_batch = X_data[index_batch, :].todense()
       counter += 1
       yield np.hstack((X_batch, scaled_array))
       if (counter > number_of_batches):
           counter = 0
```

Finally fit the model

```py
history = btc_model_4.fit(nn_batch_generator(X_train, y_train, scaled=result_train, batch_size=2), steps_per_epoch=#Todetermine,
                         batch_size=2, epochs=10,
                         callbacks=[callback])

btc_model_4.evaluate(nn_batch_generator(X_test, y_test, scaled=result_test, batch_size=2), batch_size=2, steps=#Todetermine)
y_pred = btc_model_4.predict(nn_batch_generator_test(X_test, scaled=result_test, batch_size=2), steps=#Todetermine)
```

Comment: Your solution makes sense, but the solution is too memory intensive in a large dataset I am using. Might there be a better way of doing it without crashing a runtime even with 24GB of RAM?

Comment: You could reduce the memory foot print by loading the "time" column as timestamp rather than string. Try doing `pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=["Time"], names=['Time', 'Open'])`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to the existing answer, if you do the conversion to a Pandas DataFrame from the Scipy Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) Matrix and convert the timestamp strings to datetime64, the model will start to train - at least on the small subset provided:

```
    enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")
    enc.fit(X_btc)
    X_btc = enc.transform(X_btc)
    X_btc = pd.DataFrame(X_btc.todense())
    X_btc["Time"] = btc_data["Time"]
    X_btc['Time'] = X_btc['Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Per your comment about memory intensiveness, that is the nature of how you're approaching the problem - by doing one hot encoding with timestamps, if you have a feature matrix with *n* rows each containing a distinct value (which we would expect when dealing with timestamps), applying one-hot encoding will generate an *n x n* matrix, which can be huge. To verify, if you step through or print out the intermediate matrices being generated during this process with your test data, you will observe that `X_btc` starts a *34 x 1* matrix, and becomes a becomes a *34 x 34* matrix after the encoder (`X_btc = enc.transform(X_btc)`) is applied.

I'm not sure what the end objective of this problem is, but if you wanted to continue using this approach, you may want to bin the samples in a less granular way - as in, instead of treating each timestamp down to the millisecond as it's own distinct category when one hot encoding, truncating to the hour and then applying one hot encoding:

```
    X_btc['Time'] = X_btc['Time'].astype('datetime64[h]')  # convert to units to hours before one hot encoding
    enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")
    enc.fit(X_btc)
    X_btc = enc.transform(X_btc)
    X_btc = pd.DataFrame(X_btc.todense())
    X_btc["Time"] = btc_data["Time"].astype('datetime64[ns]')  # Use 'ns' here to retain the full timestamp information
```

In the example data provided, since we have 2 different hours (12 and 13), when one hot encoding is applied, we only have 2 distinct classes now instead of 34. This should mitigate the memory issues, as you should have far fewer hours compared to total records for this data.

Along that same vein, instead of truncating to just the hour, you could just extract the hour (and possibly minute) from the timestamps to one hot encode:

```
    X_btc['Time'] = str(X_btc['Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.hour) 
    #  + ":" + str(X_btc['Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.minute) # UNCOMMENT TO INCLUDE minute
```

The benefit to this approach is if you save the encoder, you can reuse this logic on new data being ingested into the system, whereas in the current approach of encoding the training data, you wouldn't be able to run the model on a stream of data that doesn't contain dates in the training set. They would belong to a new category and require re-fitting the encoder and model.

If you use just hour, that means you will have 24 distinct classes from the one hot encoder. If you use minutes as well, you will have 24 * 60 = 1440 distinct classes (which should still be far less than the number of records you're working with).